# Using UIViewController MediaPlayer additions in iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller, media-player

I want to use the [UIViewController MediaPlayer additions](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/UIViewController_MediaPlayer_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) in an iPhone 4 static library.

The .h of my view controller subclass imports `<MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>`. However, when I use `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated` in the .m I get a compiler warning:

'MyViewController' may not respond to '-presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:animated:'

What am I doing wrong? How do I avoid this warning? Does the static library have anything to do with this?

Current code:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];
if ([MPMoviePlayerController instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) {
    // iPhone 3.2 or higher  
    MyMoviePlayerViewControllerSubclass* vc = [[MyMoviePlayerViewControllerSubclass alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:vc animated:YES];
    [vc release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:` takes a parameter of type `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

Here is an example:

```
// Initialize a movie player object with the specified URL
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    if (mp) {
        // save the movie player object
        self.moviePlayerViewController = mp;
        [mp release];

        //Present       
        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.moviePlayerViewController];

        // Play the movie!
        self.moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
        [self.moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer play];
    }
```

Where url is the url of the movie, and self.moviePlayerViewController is a property var (if you need one) of type MPMoviePlayerViewController.

Comment: I'm passing an instance of a MPMoviePlayerViewController subclass. Is that the problem?

Comment: That should be fine -- are you using the iOS 4 SDK?

Comment: Yes. The Base SDK is iPhone Device 4.0 and the iPhone OS Deployment Target is iPhone OS 3.1.

Comment: Where are you calling `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated`? Maybe you should post some code so we can see what's going on more clearly.

Comment: This answer contained a crucial clue for a different problem I was having, where the movie controls don't appear immediately. The answer is telling the movie player in advance that it's a MPMovieSourceTypeFile.

Answer (score 0):

if these additions are in a static library then you need to make sure your main project has additional linker flags set, otherwise the compiler will ignore the extensions.

go into your build settings for your main project, and under linker flags make sure you have the following set:

-ObjC -all_load